# Removing black lines between merged tiles?

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, tiles, interpolation

I merged several rasters, but there is a problem with lines between sheets.

Raster is created from LiDAR datasets. Rasters were produced from different datasets via this application: [https://iaps.zrc-sazu.si/en/rvt#v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMNoF.jpg) and then merged.

For merging I used `Raster > Miscellaneous > Merge` in QGis 2.18.15.

Please see snapshot of a problem:

[image]

And the Merge function pop-up:

[image]

I found that even between unmerged sheets there is some minimal space:

[image]

How do I get rid of those lines?

Probably the original sin is already in the input.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: while merging your rasters, which option did you use? (sum, mean, first etc..)

Comment: .@PolyGeo - I am using QGis 2.18.15
@vale: I merged rasters in QGis via Raster>Miscellaneous>Merge.
I have added additional information in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the black lines are pixels with missing data (no data). In this case, some options are:

- i) **start over** by accessing the raw point cloud data and generate a DEM with a method that process tiles altogether so to avoid having edge's artifacts. Take a look at [Merging multiple LiDAR (.las) files?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297745/merging-multiple-lidar-las-files/297749#297749).
- ii) **interpolate** (fill in no data values) while keeping same resolution. There are plenty of methods and tools for this. See for example, [Interpolate smoothly nodata values in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293602/interpolate-smoothly-nodata-values-in-qgis) and [How to fill gaps in SLC-Off Landsat 7 ETM+ Images with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30250/how-to-fill-gaps-in-slc-off-landsat-7-etm-images-with-qgis/30316#30316)
- iii) **resample** (which is also interpolation) to a coarser resolution. See [Deciding what interpolation method to use for resampling raster data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2587/deciding-what-interpolation-method-to-use-for-resampling-raster-data) and [Pros and Cons of using Bilinear Interpolation and Cubic Convolution when dealing with DEMs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267433/pros-and-cons-of-using-bilinear-interpolation-and-cubic-convolution-when-dealing/267441#267441).